# How to defend against accidentally shadowing the standard library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm new to Python, and wrote a utility script that generates some numbers I need. I named the file `numbers.py`. This script depends on the PyGame library. I found that just importing that library caused errors, because PyGame tries to `import numbers` from the Python standard library, and the default lookup rules have my own file shadowing the standard library.

The linters I have tried (PyLint, Ruff) do not seem to catch this rookie mistake of mine, but I'm having trouble understanding how best to avoid it. As best as I can tell, the advice to "just rename your files" to not collide with the standard library requires either:

1. memorizing the 307 standard library names (that don't have periods; 1027 names in total), or
2. being able to recognize via errors from other libraries that maybe you accidentally shadowed a library, so you can rename

I'm hoping there's a better solution, like `#include <foo>` vs `#include "foo"` that would differentiate between the standard library and a local file, or a lint configuration that detects when a file I create shadows the standard library.

How can I avoid this problem as I go forward?

```
phrogz:~/proj/ai$ ls
numbers.py

phrogz:~/proj/ai$ cat numbers.py 
import pygame

phrogz:~/proj/ai$ python numbers.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/phrogz/proj/ai/numbers.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/home/phrogz/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 264, in <module>
    import pygame.surfarray
  File "/home/phrogz/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pygame/surfarray.py", line 47, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/home/phrogz/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "/home/phrogz/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
  File "/home/phrogz/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from . import numerictypes as nt
  File "/home/phrogz/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 595, in <module>
    _register_types()
  File "/home/phrogz/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/numerictypes.py", line 590, in _register_types
    numbers.Integral.register(integer)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Integral'
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for.  This error was was immediately visible and now you know to fix it, so what specifically are you trying to avoid?

Comment: In practice, once you get past the initial learning phase, most of the code you write is probably going to be within a package. You don't have to worry about name clashes with anything outside the package, as long as the package itself doesn't clash with anything. I'm surprised the linters didn't catch this, though.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm looking for a technique--coding syntax, file placement, dev environment, tools, etc.--that either yells at me when I name a file that would shadow the stdlib, or (ideally) makes it so that I can name my own files whatever I want without fear of breaking code in some library I import. In fact, it was not immediately obvious what broke and caused the issue; I thought at first there was a problem with the PyGame install. (And, in spite of my question details, I actually happened to put the offending "numbers.py" adjacent to what was previously a working script.)

Comment: I don't know if this is really helpful but if you very early in your code `import sys` and then `sys.path = sys.path[1:] + sys.path[:1]`, the usually prepended local directory is appended and stdlib is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue happens because when running

```
python myscript.py
```

The directory of `myscript.py` gets *prepended* to the `sys.path`. The prepend means that your own module is found by import statements *before* any library modules.

Since this is a "feature" (ability to monkeypatch stdlib), it is unlikely to change any time soon, but Python 3.11+ does provide ways to opt-out of that potentially unsafe behavior with [command-line options](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-P) and [environment variables](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSAFEPATH):

> **-P**
>
> Don’t prepend a potentially unsafe path to `sys.path`:
>
> - `python -m module` command line: Don’t prepend the current working directory.
> - `python script.py` command line: Don’t prepend the script’s directory. If it’s a symbolic link, resolve symbolic links.
> - `python -c code` and `python` (REPL) command lines: Don’t prepend an empty string, which means the current working directory.

See also the [PYTHONSAFEPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSAFEPATH) environment variable.

This ensures only stdlib and installed modules are picked up by `import`, and avoids unintentionally or maliciously shadowing modules with those in a local (and typically user-writable) directory.

ref: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/31542

Comment: Also fixed this at work one time I believe by using a relative path and "as", I'm not sure if the as is actually required.
from ..lib import numbers as num (this has been updated since and I don't believe it works anymore)

Comment: This looks like it answers the question well, thanks! (Feels it would be nice to have an option that changed prepend to *append*, but I'll have to get more experience with Python dev before I know if that's really an issue.)